i am trying to implement a newsfeed API in my laravel app. i am currently using laravel 11
I am getting the error message on the route to the news index function:

Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider

I have set up the API keys and the service providers but still getting the error above.
My NewsController is as follows:
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    protected $mediastackService;

    public function __construct(MediastackService $mediastackService)
    {
        $this->mediastackService = $mediastackService;
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $parameters = $request->get();
        $news = $this->mediastackService->getNews($parameters);

        return response()->json($news);
    }
}

My mediastackservice.php is as follows:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MediastackService extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
    }

    protected $baseUrl = 'http://api.mediastack.com/v1';

    public function getNews($parameters = [])
    {
        $response = Http::get($this->baseUrl . '/news', array_merge([
            'access_key' => config('services.mediastack.key'),
        ], $parameters));

        if ($response->successful()) {
            return $response->json();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

Kindly help out.

Your problems will be coming from the fact that you have set your service up as a service provider - which is definitely not what you want to be doing.
It is a service class, but it is not a service provider.
Follow these steps to get it working properly:

Move the mediastackservice.php to app/Services/MediastackService.php
Update MediastackService.php to look like the below:

<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class MediastackService
{
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://api.mediastack.com/v1';

    public function getNews($parameters = [])
    {
        $response = Http::get($this->baseUrl . '/news', array_merge([
            'access_key' => config('services.mediastack.key'),
        ], $parameters));

        if ($response->successful()) {
            return $response->json();
        }

        return null;
    }
}


Update your NewsController to import the service from the new namespace

- use App\Providers\MediastackService;
+ use App\Services\MediastackService;

This should resolve the app dependency issue that you are seeing.
